# Non-Scrolling tabbar in UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbar

I have a ViewController and added a UIScrollView to that view.Now I want to have a tabbar at the bottom of the view.The tabbar items doesnot contain the current view being displayed.So I have gone for UITabbar instead of tabbarController.But the problem is since the view is scrollable when I add a tabbar to the view it is also scrollable.I want to make tabbar static which resides at the bottom of the view.My ViewController nd its outlets are like this:

I have a view(Profile) which is scrollable and I have (Search,Login)as tabbar items with none selected as default while displaying Edit Profile.How can I add a static tabbar in the present view.Currently I m getting like this:

Do I have to consider any subview?

Any advice/suggestions would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Why dont you keep the tab bar outside the scroll view? I mean scroll view between tab bar and top.

You can also use table view and set its footer...but if you paste a screen shot it will be help full

This is what the end build looks like ihave kept the tab bar out side...

Comment: but im connecting the outlet of view to scrollview.in such a case what should i do?let me paste my screen shots.

Comment: I have edited my question with screenshots.Can u please have a look and let me know

Comment: you want the tab bar in the bottom? and on selection of tabbar item want to change the content of scroll view?

Comment: yes i want it in the bottom.not to be scrolled along with scrollview and when tabbaritem is selected then its corresponding view will be displayed.

Comment: My best guess is you can keep the tab bar on outside view and shorten the height of scroll view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21891/discussion-between-amar-and-sindhia)

Comment: I can do when a corresponding tabbar item is selected to display the corresponding view.But how to make UITabbar non scrollable?

Comment: view is connected to what?Filesowner or scrollview?show me the utilities view.and can u see both scrollview and tabbar?

Comment: View is connected to filesowner.. may be we are not on the same page..will try experimenting ..if i get any thing will post